# rsync permissions question -- destination perms not properly applying

Tags: linux, debian, rsync

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
rsync -rvl --chmod=ug=rwX,o=rX test /var/www
```

and after I do it, here are the results I get:

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

(Actually it's drwxr-sr-x, but that's probably not important ... is it?)

This, obviously is not what I want. I want the group to have write permissions, but for some reason, the rsync command isn't setting them.

Anyone have any ideas why not? Is there a mistake in my syntax? If it's helpful I'm transferring from OSX to Linux (Debian).

**Update:**
Also, if it's helpful, when I enter umask, I get 0002. So that's not the problem.

Comment: Which end is that umask on? And what is it on the other end?

Comment: @SimonJ, the umask of 0002 is on the server end, on my local end it's 0022.

Comment: Presumably the server is the Linux box (i.e. the destination)?

Comment: This looks like a useful topic, but one that should be migrated to, say, Unix.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`--chmod` overrides the *sending* side permissions, but if you don't specify `-p` or `--perms` as well then the destination defaults are used regardless (i.e. `--chmod` is ignored).

From [man 1 rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

> **--chmod**
>
> This option tells rsync to apply  one  or  more  comma-separated
>     "chmod"  strings to the permission of the files in the transfer.
>     The resulting value is treated as though it was the  permissions
>     that  the  sending  side supplied for the file, which means that
>     **this option can seem to have no  effect  on  existing  files  if
>     --perms is not enabled**.

Answer (score 20):

You have to use `--chmod` with `-p` options, like this:

```
$ rsync -avz --chmod=o-rwx -p tata/ tata2/
```

And here is a full test:

#### Create some file in a folder

```
$ mkdir tata
$ mkdir tata2
$ cd tata
$ touch tyoto
$ touch tiuti
```

#### The default perms are: `u=rw, g=r, o=r`

```
$ ls -l 
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 romain users 0 fév 16 11:48 tiuti
-rw-r--r-- 1 romain users 0 fév 16 11:48 tyoto
```

#### Try an rsync without params

```
$ cd ..
$ rsync -avz tata/ tata2/
```

#### The destination perms are the same than the source files

```
$ ls -l tata2
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 romain users 0 fév 16 11:48 tiuti
-rw-r--r-- 1 romain users 0 fév 16 11:48 tyoto
```

#### Specify the rsync options `--chmod=o-rwx -p`

```
$ rsync -avz --chmod=o-rwx -p tata/ tata2/
$ ls -l tata2
total 0
-rw-r----- 1 romain users 0 fév 16 11:48 tiuti
-rw-r----- 1 romain users 0 fév 16 11:48 tyoto
```

#### And now your perms are ok.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to add `--perms` (aka `-p`).  Quoting from the manpage:

> When this option is off, permissions are set as follows:
>
> ...
>
> New  files  get their "normal" permission bits set to the
>                        source  file's  permissions  masked  with  the  receiving
>                        directory's  default  permissions  (either  the receiving
>                        process's umask, or the  permissions  specified  via  the
>                        destination  directory's  default ACL), and their special
>                        permission bits disabled except in the case where  a  new
>                        directory  inherits  a  setgid bit from its parent directory.

I suspect your destination system has a typical umask like 022 which is preventing the group write bit from being set by rsync.  Unfortunately `--chmod` doesn't mention how the umask does or does not apply.

Comment: I don't want to use -p because my local files don't have group write permissions either. My umask is set to 0002, so I don't believe that's causing the problem.